# Пунктуация в предложении (2)

Tags: пунктуация

*Одна из самых известных связанных с ним историй случилась в 1905 году.*

Какие знаки препинания нужны в этом предложении?

Answer (score 3):

Предложение написано правильно, ***знаки препинания не нужны.***

Причастие "связанных" стоит перед определяемым словом "историй", а в таких случаях запятые не ставят. Обособление было бы необходимо при такой фразе:

*Одна из самых известных историй, связанных с ним, случилась в 1905 году.*

Comment: лучше сказать "знаки препинания не нужны"

Comment: Наверно, Вы правы, спасибо.)